# Printing the value of integer data type using %x in printf statement

Tags: c, octal, numeral-system

Got confused with the following peice of code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a=0100;
printf("%x",a);
}
```

The value I am getting is 40.

Can someone explain me whats going on here?

Note : When I removed the digit 0 before digit 1 then its coming 64 which is correct, when 100 is converted into hex.

[Codepad link to above code](http://codepad.org/DbNWcSbG)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, a constant prefixed with a `0` is an **octal** constant. 0100 in base 8 is 
1000000 in base 2, which is 40 in hexadecimal, which is 64 in base 10. So your program is printing exactly what it should.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: but we are assigning the value of 0100 to integer data type a. Then why the conversion to octal?

Comment: The C compiler treats any numeric constant starting with `0` as an octal value. The integer variable doesn't care about the numeric base of the constant in the source code - everything in the computer is stored in base 2 (binary) anyways, so whether the numeric constant in the source code is base 10, or base 8, or base 16 makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
int a=0100;
```

you are assigning an *octal* value, which is 64 in base 10 and 40 is hex.

An integer literal starting with a `0` is octal in C.

Answer (score 1):

a 0 prefix in c means octal, not decimal.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

> - decimal-literal is a non-zero decimal digit (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
>     9), followed by zero or more decimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
>     8, 9)
> - octal-literal is the digit zero (0) followed by zero or more
>     octal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
> - hex-literal is the character
>     sequence 0x or the character sequence 0X followed by one or more
>     hexadecimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, A, b, B, c, C, d,
>     D, e, E, f, F)
> - binary-literal is the character sequence 0b or the
>     character sequence 0B followed by one or more binary digits (0, 1)

Answer (score 1):

**0100** is a octal value as it has prefix `0`.

```
0100 in octal (base 8)
 ^~~~(8^2)*1

is same as  

0x40  in hexadecimal (base 16)
  ^~~~(16^1)*4   // %x is for hexadecimal format

is same as 

64 in decimal (base 10)

printf("%o %x %d",a, a, a);  // prints 100 40 64
```